# Close or shutdown of H2 database after tests is not working

Tags: scala, h2, slick, scalatest

I am facing a problem of database clean-up after each test when using scalatest with Slick.

Here is code of the test:

```
class H2DatabaseSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with ScalaFutures with BeforeAndAfter {
  implicit override val patienceConfig = PatienceConfig(timeout = Span(5, Seconds))

  val h2DB: H2DatabaseService = new H2DatabaseService
  var db: Database = _

  before {
    db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
    h2DB.createSchema.futureValue
  }

  after {
    db.shutdown.futureValue
  }

  "H2 database" should {
    "query a question" in {
      val newQuestion: QuestionEntity = QuestionEntity(Some(1L), "First question")
      h2DB.insertQuestion(newQuestion).futureValue

      val question = h2DB.getQuestionById(1L)

      question.futureValue.get shouldBe newQuestion
    }
  }

  it should {
    "query all questions" in {
      val newQuestion: QuestionEntity = QuestionEntity(Some(2L), "Second question")
      h2DB.insertQuestion(newQuestion).futureValue

      val questions = h2DB.getQuestions

      questions.futureValue.size shouldBe 1
    }
  }
}
```

Database service is just invoking `run` method on defined database:

```
class H2DatabaseService {

  val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")

  val questions = TableQuery[Question]

  def createSchema =
    db.run(questions.schema.create)

  def getQuestionById(id: Long): Future[Option[QuestionEntity]] =
    db.run(questions.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)

  def getQuestions: Future[Seq[QuestionEntity]] =
    db.run(questions.result)

  def insertQuestion(question: QuestionEntity): Future[Int] =
    db.run(questions += question)
}

class Question(tag: Tag) extends Table[QuestionEntity](tag, "QUESTION") {
  def id = column[Option[Long]]("QUESTION_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def title = column[String]("TITLE")

  def * = (id, title) <> ((QuestionEntity.apply _).tupled, QuestionEntity.unapply)
}

case class QuestionEntity(id: Option[Long] = None, title: String) {
  require(!title.isEmpty, "title.empty")
}
```

And the database is defined as follows:

```
h2mem1 = {
  url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test1"
  driver = org.h2.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
}
```

I am using Scala 2.11.8, Slick 3.1.1, H2 database 1.4.192 and scalatest 2.2.6.

Error that appears when tests are executed is `Table "QUESTION" already exists`. So it looks like `shutdown()` method has no effect at all (but it is invoked - checked in debugger).

Anybody knows how to handle such scenario? How to clean-up database properly after each test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database has not been correctly cleaned-up because of invoking the method on different object.

`H2DatabaseService` has it's own `db` object and the test it's own. Issue was fixed after refactoring H2 database service and invoking:

```
after {
  h2DB.db.shutdown.futureValue
}
```